# knapsack optimization using Python pulp - how to set constraints?

Tags: python, optimization, constants, knapsack-problem, pulp

I want to develop inventory fulfillment optimization model. I want to fulfil from Plt_Inv to WH_Inv if WH_Inv is less than SS for each SKUs, with total fulfillment volume should be less than 10000KG.

I write my code as below and also show results.  but I receive status as " infeasible" and results does not match to the requirements.    I assume that the constraints model is not correct. Can anyone help to see where are incorrect codes.

---

```
import pandas as pd
!pip install pulp
import pulp
```

### Dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SS':[10,20,100,5,500],'SKU':['A','B','C','D','E']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'WH_Inv':[30,15,200,7,300],'SKU':['A','B','C','D','E']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Plt_Inv':[100,0,300,0,100],'SKU':['A','B','C','D','E']})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'KG':[20,12,10,12,20],'SKU':['A','B','C','D','E']})
```

### Define list

```
SKU = df1['SKU'].tolist()
SS =df1['SS'].tolist()
WH =df2['WH_Inv'].tolist()
PLT = df3['Plt_Inv'].tolist()
KG = df4['KG'].tolist()
```

### Define constant

```
safety = {row.SKU:row.SS for row in df1.itertuples()}
warehouse = {row.SKU:row.WH_Inv for row in df2.itertuples()}
plant = {row.SKU:row.Plt_Inv for row in df3.itertuples()}
kgs = {row.SKU:row.KG for row in df4.itertuples()}
```

### Optimization Model

```
problem =pulp.LpProblem('Optimization',pulp.LpMaximize)
```

### Set variables

```
x={}
 for s in SKU:

  x[s]=pulp.LpVariable(f'x_{s}',cat='Integer')
```

### Constraints

```
for s in SKU:
    problem += x[s]>=0
    problem+= x[s]>= safety[s]
    problem+= x[s]<= plant[s]
    problem += pulp.lpDot(x[s],KG)<=10000
```

### Objective

```
problem += pulp.lpDot(x[s],KG)
```

### Solve

```
status = problem.solve()
print('status:',pulp.LpStatus[status])

for s in SKU:
  print(s,x[s].value())
  print('obj=', problem.objective.value())
```

### Results:  Status is infeasible and fulfillment qty does not match to requirements

status: Infeasible
A 10.0
B 0.0
C 100.0
D 0.0
E 500.0
obj= 37000.0